# Stoping condition of recursive method doesn't work at the right time

Tags: ruby

A peculiar problem is ocurring with me. I'm coding a binary search tree with some methods:

```
class BinarySearchTree
  class Node
    attr_accessor :value, :height
    attr_accessor :left, :right

    def initialize(value, height)
      @value = value
      @height = height
    end
  end

 attr_accessor :root

def initialize
  @root = Node.new(nil, 0)
end

def insert(value)
  node = @root
  loop do
    case value <=> node.value
    when -1
      if node.left.nil?
        node.left = Node.new(value, node.height + 1)
        break
      else
        node = node.left
      end
    when 1
      if node.right.nil?
        node.right = Node.new(value, node.height + 1)
        break
      else
        node = node.right
      end
    else
      node.value = value
      break
    end
  end
end

def delete(value, node = @root)
  return if node.nil?
  if value == node.value
    node = delete_node(node)
  elsif value < node.value
    node.left = delete(value, node.left)
  elsif
    node.right = delete(value, node.right)
  end
  node
end

def delete_node(node)
  if node.left.nil? && node.right.nil?
    node = nil
  elsif node.left.nil? || node.right.nil?
    if node.left.nil?
      node = node.right
      update_subtrees_height(node, -1, {left: false, right: true})
    else
      node = node.right end
      update_subtrees_height(node, -1, {left: true, right: false})
  else
    #TODO
  end
  node
end

def update_subtrees_height(node, value, options = {left: true, right: true})
  return if node.nil?
  node.height = node.height + value
  update_subtrees_height(node.left, value, options) if options[:left]
  update_subtrees_height(node.right, value, options) if options[:right]
end

# For debug
def print_tree(node = @root)
  return if node.nil?
  puts "#{node.left.nil? ? 'null' : node.left.value} - #{node.nil? ? 'null' : node.value}(H#{node.height}) - #{node.right.nil? ? 'null' : node.right.value}"
  print_tree(node.left)
  print_tree(node.right)
end
end
```

The problem occurs in the `update_subtrees_height`. Consider this test:

```
bTree = BinarySearchTree.new

[8,7,9,10].each do |v|
  bTree.insert(v)
end

bTree.print_tree bTree.root
bTree.root = bTree.delete(9)
bTree.print_tree bTree.root
```

Step by step, this test does:

1) Buil the tree and print it (the output is from my `print_tree` method):

```
7 - 8(H0) - 9
null - 7(H1) - null
null - 9(H1) - 10
null - 10(H2) - null
```

That represents the following tree:

```
   8     # Height 0
  / \
 7   9   # Height 1
      \
      10 # Height 2
```

2) Delete the 9 from the tree and print it again:

```
7 - 8(H0) - 10
null - 7(H1) - null
null - 10(H0) - null
```

As showed in the output, the height of the child 10 (represented with a `H` in the output) is 0, when should be 1. That hapens why when I call my recursive method `update_subtrees_height`, it's called two times before stop. But what I do removing the 9 is replace it with its right child, the 10, and then I call `update_subtrees_height` passing the node 10 to decrease its height.

Calling this update method, I've the stoping condition `return if node.nil?`. With the node 10, I doesn't stop at the first iteration, decreaing its height to 1 (the desired result) and call the method recursivly, passing node.right. My node.right is nil, but the method doesn't stop at the next iteration (!), decreasing the height of the node 10 again (to 0 this time, the output that I had). At the third iteration, the method stop.

Someone have any idea why this third iteration happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your `delete_node` method:

```
def delete_node(node)
  if node.left.nil? && node.right.nil?
    node = nil
  elsif node.left.nil? || node.right.nil?
    if node.left.nil?
      node = node.right
      update_subtrees_height(node, -1, {left: false, right: true})
    else
      node = node.right end
 #                     ^^^
      update_subtrees_height(node, -1, {left: true, right: false})
  else
    #TODO
  end
  node
end
```

Fix it to the following and all will work!

```
def delete_node(node)
  if node.left.nil? && node.right.nil?
    node = nil
  elsif node.left.nil? || node.right.nil?
    if node.left.nil?
      node = node.right
      update_subtrees_height(node, -1, {left: false, right: true})
    else
      node = node.right
      update_subtrees_height(node, -1, {left: true, right: false})
    end
  else
    #TODO
  end
  node
end
```

Comment: It's amazing how sometimes these details become "invisible" when debbuging. Thanks a lot!